# Do you cache the LoadLibrary HINSTANCE?

Tags: c++, mfc

Here is sample code:

```
CString CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::GetStudyPointDescriptionEx(bool b2019Format, const int iStudyPoint, const bool bFormatText /*false*/)
{
    CString strDescription = _T("<ERROR>");
    LANGUAGE_E eForeignLanguage = GetForeignLanguageGroupLanguageID();

    if (iStudyPoint == 0)
        strDescription = _T("");
    else
    {
        if (UseTranslationINI(eForeignLanguage))
        {
            // Snipped
        }
        else
        {
            HINSTANCE hInst = nullptr;

            if (eForeignLanguage != LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
                hInst = LoadLibrary(theApp.GetForeignLanguageGroupSatelliteDLLPath());
            else
                hInst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();

            if (b2019Format)
                strDescription.LoadString(hInst, IDS_STR_NEW_STUDY_POINT_01 + (iStudyPoint - 1));
            else
                strDescription.LoadString(hInst,  + (iStudyPoint - 1));

            if (eForeignLanguage != LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
                FreeLibrary(hInst);
        }

        if (bFormatText) // AJT v16.0.9
        {
            CString strFormattedText;

            strFormattedText.Format(_T("%d - %s"), iStudyPoint, (LPCTSTR)strDescription);
            strDescription = strFormattedText;
        }
    }

    return strDescription;
}
```

Notice the function calls to load the DLL resource file?

It works fine. My question:

Should I load this DLL file **once** and **cache** the `HINSTANCE` in the application class until the user changes their mind, or should I constantly load and unload as I need to extract a custom resource value?

Comment: I'd not cache anything. The user isn't changing the UI language 100 times per second. So IMO it's not important if switching the UI language takes 10ms or 500ms. Anyway on any moderen hardware (< 10 years old or so) loading .dll is fast and the filesystem cache will be there anyway.

Comment: On a second thought I probably misread your question, but anyway if you don't call `GetStudyPointDescriptionEx` very often, it's probably not worth doing caching. Did you notice any slowness with `eForeignLanguage != LANGUAGE_ENGLISH` vs. `eForeignLanguage == LANGUAGE_ENGLISH`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky No I did not notice. I have a schedule that displays a certain amount of locale based information . The schedule is for a month of assignments. Up until now I always got the schedule to display all data using the active locale of the GUI. But now the user can override the locale used for the schedule content. I have not tried the `if` you referred to. Why would that logic necessarily be faster? Simpler comparison?

Comment: Maybe loading/unloading the dll repeatedly may be noticebly slower than loading the DLL once and for all, maybe not. Try it and if you don't notice any significant difference, I'd just list leave it like that.

Comment: Well, two comments. 1) If it is an MFC DLL,there is a place in the dynamic link library list of MFC to store the resource handle of localized DLLs. 2) I'd use LoadLibraryEx with the flag to load as data/resources. Saves trying to do any runtime startup, static variable initialization, calling DllMain() etc when you don't really need any of that.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson OK, I have used `m_hInstanceSatelliteDLL = LoadLibraryEx(GetForeignLanguageGroupSatelliteDLLPath(), NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);` but I am not aware of this place for resource handles. I have the mast one as defined by MFC but this secondary one I use my own handle variable. Also, do you still just use `FreeLibrary` with this `LoadLibraryEx`?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson OK, I see in the article to use `FreeLibrary` still. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Why use the exclusive flag?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, that was a typo. I deleted the comment. Rewriting here: .... Use `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE|LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`. It appears your have a "resource only DLL". I don't think you gain anything by unloading this DLL. You might as well use global variables, example `hinstance_language1`, initialized to zero, and load it once when required.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle If you look in the CDynLinkLibrary class, you will see that every MFC library you initialize should have a CDynLinkLibrary instance. They have two members: m_hModule and m_hResource. m_hResource is the place to put the instance handle of your localized DLL.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani OK, I have rectified my code.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Ah, OK. I use the `m_hResource` variable already for the primary language resources. This is a secondary file for custom resources so I use my own variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on all of the comments kindly provided it was decided to **cache** the resources. So, I now load the resources into a member variable of the application class. This is only done once, at the point the user changes the setting. Thereafter the application uses the cached instance.

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::LoadForeignLanguageGroupSatelliteFile()
{
    LANGUAGE_E eForeignLanguage = GetForeignLanguageGroupLanguageID();

    ResetForeignLanguageGroupResources();

    // Load the new foreign language resources
    if (UseTranslationINI(eForeignLanguage))
        ReadTranslationINI(m_SatelliteINI, eForeignLanguage, true);
    else
    {
        if (eForeignLanguage == LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)
            m_hInstanceSatelliteDLL = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
        else
            m_hInstanceSatelliteDLL = LoadLibraryEx(GetForeignLanguageGroupSatelliteDLLPath(), nullptr,
                LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    }
}


void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::ResetForeignLanguageGroupResources()
{
    if (m_hInstanceSatelliteDLL != nullptr)
    {
        FreeLibrary(m_hInstanceSatelliteDLL);
        m_hInstanceSatelliteDLL = nullptr;
    }
    m_SatelliteINI.clear();
}
```

Since this is an additional set of resources to the primary GUI interface the instance is stored in a custom variable and not the system variable `m_hResource`.

Therefore, the method shown in my original question now looks like:

```
CString CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::GetStudyPointDescriptionEx(bool b2019Format, const int iStudyPoint, const bool bFormatText /*false*/)
{
    CString strDescription = _T("<ERROR>");
    LANGUAGE_E eForeignLanguage = GetForeignLanguageGroupLanguageID();

    if (iStudyPoint == 0)
        strDescription = _T("");
    else
    {
        if (UseTranslationINI(eForeignLanguage))
        {
            CString strLabel, strKey = _T("StudyPoints");

            if (b2019Format)
            {
                strKey = _T("StudyPoints2019");
                strLabel.Format(_T("IDS_STR_NEW_STUDY_POINT_%02d"), iStudyPoint);
            }
            else
                strLabel.Format(_T("IDS_STR_STUDY_POINT_%02d"), iStudyPoint);

            // AJT v17.1.3 We now use our own method
            strDescription = theApp.GetStringFromTranslationINI(m_SatelliteINI, strKey, strLabel);
        }
        else
        {
            if (b2019Format)
                strDescription.LoadString(m_hInstanceSatelliteDLL, IDS_STR_NEW_STUDY_POINT_01 + (iStudyPoint - 1));
            else
                strDescription.LoadString(m_hInstanceSatelliteDLL,  + (iStudyPoint - 1));
        }

        if (bFormatText) // AJT v16.0.9
        {
            CString strFormattedText;

            strFormattedText.Format(_T("%d - %s"), iStudyPoint, (LPCTSTR)strDescription);
            strDescription = strFormattedText;
        }
    }

    return strDescription;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could summarize the reasons that let to the decision to cache the DLL handle. Right now one has to wade through the comments to figure it.

Comment: @zett42 I think the question comes down to: Is it more efficient to call `LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary` 100 times, or call `LoadLibrary` just once?

Comment: @Andrew I think you misunderstood my earlier suggestion. The code in your question was okay. It was calling `LoadLibraryEx/FreeLibrary` multiple times. With this code, it is calling `LoadLibraryEx` multiple times (maybe less often than before), but there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to call `FreeLibrary`. My suggestion was to call `LoadLibrary/Ex` once.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani No no, my code is called once by the menu event handler and it frees the previous library and loads the new. Then my application uses that cached library. Previously I was loading it every time I wanted to extract a string from the DLL.

Comment: I have this feeling WIN32 is caching the DLL's in the back. But why guessing. Why not just comparing the cached and non-cached methods? I mean benchmarking. If it turns out non-cached is noticeably slower then implement your own dll cache.